# Printing the elements of a linked list

Tags: python, object-oriented, linked-list

An absolute beginner here who is practising linked list problems in hackerrank. Stumbled upon this question which is categorised as easy.
Given a pointer to the head node of the linked list, print each node's data element. Link to question https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/print-the-elements-of-a-linked-list/problem?isFullScreen=true

```
class SinglyLinkedListNode:
    def __init__(self, node_data):
        self.data = node_data
        self.next = None

class SinglyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def insert_node(self, node_data):
        node = SinglyLinkedListNode(node_data)

        if not self.head:
            self.head = node
        else:
            self.tail.next = node
        
        self.tail = node

def printLinkedList(head):
    while head is not None:
        print(head.data, end="\n")
        head = head.next
    print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    llist_count = int(input())

    llist = SinglyLinkedList()

    for _ in range(llist_count):
        llist_item = int(input())
        llist.insert_node(llist_item)

    printLinkedList(llist.head)
```

I have 2 questions about the code which I'm struggling to understand.

1. In the `printLinkedList` function, why must it be `print(head.data)` and not just  `print(head)`
2. Referring to the same line `print(head.data)`, the head is probably `SinglyLinkedList().head` I assume, but is there a `data` attribute in the class?

Would appreciate if anyone could shed some light on my doubts.

Comment: If this is not your code, then this question is off-topic. You can only post your own code here. These questions are better asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Even if it is your own code, you are expected to understand why it's written the way it is - asking for explanations is explicitly off-topic for code review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question:

Each node in the list has a `data` and `next` attribute and we wish to print all the `data` attribute values by walking through the list. We have a choice in how we can design function `printLinkedList` to be called: (1) We pass it a  `SinglyLinkedList` instance such as `llist` or the first node of `llist`, namely `llist.head`. The second option was chosen. If we printed `head` instead of `head.data`, it would be printing out a `SinglyLinkedListNode` instance and the output would look something like `<__main__.SinglyLinkedListNode object at 0x000001D5FCB4F820`. But since we wish to print out the `data` attribute values, we print `head.data` instead. I do think a better design would be to pass instead the linked list instance itself:

```py
def printLinkedList(linked_list):
    node = linked_list.head
    while node:
        print(node.data) # end='\n' is not required
        node = node.next
    print()
```

You might even wish to make this a method of the `SinglyLinkedList` class replacing all references to `linked_list` with `self` since the client of this class should not be concerned with how it's implemented.

To answer your second question:

If you execute `SinglyLinkedList().head` you have created an empty list where the `head` attribute will have a value of `None`. But I would say that the `head` attribute is an *instance* attribute and not a *class* attribute. If it were a class attribute you would be able to say `SinglyLinkedList.head` without having created in actual instance of this class.

The following may be a bit advanced for you, but I would prefer to redesign the classes to *encapsulate* their implementation and to expose to a client the bare minimum they need to use the classes. So the only thing that should be exposed is the class `SinglyLinkedList` because there is no need for a client to know that it iternally uses `SinglyListNode` instances to implement it. I would also provide a general method for iterating the elements of the list and then the user can implement any print logic using this capability:

```py
class SinglyLinkedList:
    class SinglyLinkedListNode:
        def __init__(self, node_data):
            self._data = node_data
            self._next = None


    def __init__(self):
        self._head = None
        self._tail = None

    def insert_node(self, node_data):
        node = SinglyLinkedList.SinglyLinkedListNode(node_data)

        if not self._head:
            self._head = node
        else:
            self._tail._next = node

        self._tail = node

    def __iter__(self):
        class SinglyLinkedListIterator:
            def __init__(self, linked_list):
                self._current_node = linked_list._head

            def __iter__(self):
                return self

            def __next__(self):
                if self._current_node:
                    node_data = self._current_node._data
                    self._current_node = self._current_node._next
                    return node_data

                raise StopIteration

        return SinglyLinkedListIterator(self)


def printLinkedList(linked_list):
    for node_data in linked_list:
        print(node_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    node_count = int(input('Enter the number of nodes in the list: ')) #Booboo

    llist = SinglyLinkedList()

    for _ in range(node_count):
        node_data = int(input('Enter the next node value (an integer): '))
        llist.insert_node(node_data)

    printLinkedList(llist)
```

Note that the client is only needs to use the `insert_node` method and is given the ability to iterate all the data values that have been added. There is no need to know about any attributes used to implement the list and therefore the names of the attributes start with '_' to suggest to a client that these are *private* attributes not to be referenced by the client.

**Python Iterators**

When you have a class instance that is a collection of items, you would like to be able to *iterate* those elements, i.e. enumerate each element one by one. To accomplish this you implement an instance method named `__iter__`:

```py
class Foo:
    """A collection of items."""
    ...
    def __iter__(self):
        """Return an iterator for this collection""".
        ...

foo = Foo()
... # Add elements to foo

# Iterate through all the items in the collection:
iterator = foo.__iter__() # Or equivalently: iterator = iter(foo)
try:
    while True:
        # Get next item:
        item = iterator.__next__() # Or  equivalently: item = next(iterator)
        ... # Do something with item
except StopExecption:
    pass # StopException is raised when there are no more items
```

So the iterator instance that is returned must support method `__next__`, which is called repeatedly to get each item in the collection until there are no more items left to iterate. When this occurs a `StopException` exception is raised.

But there is an easier syntax you can use to iterate such a collection, i.e. `for/in`:

```py
for item in foo:
    ... # Do something with item
```

The above code is equivalent to the `try/except` blocks in the previous coding example.

Quite often a collection's `__iter__(self)` method just returns `self`, i.e. the collection instance is the iterator:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._container = [] # for holding the items

    def add_item(self, item):
        self._container.append(item)

    def __iter__(self):
        # Initialize for iteration:
        self._current_index = 0
        return self

        # Note the following:
        # Since self._container is a list instance, which already 
        # supports iteration, we could have implemented this method
        # simply with: return iter(self._container)

    def __next__(self):
        # Any more items to iterate?
        if self._current_index < len(self._container):
            item = self._container[self._current_index]
            self._current_index += 1
            return item
        # No more items to iterate:
        raise StopException

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

Note that we did not really need to implement a `__iter__` method in `FooIterator` since the only method that should be called on the iterator is `__next__`. But this allows a client to code:

```py
foo = Foo()
for item in iter(foo):
    ...
```

However, the problem with a container being its own iterator is that you cannot correctly perform multiple iterations on the container concurrently:

```py
# The following does not work!

# Multiply every element in foo by every other element:
for item1 in foo:
    for item2 in foo:
        print(item1 * item2)
```

A problem arises since `foo` is the iterator instance for both loops and each loop iteration will be updating the same `self._index` variable. To support multiple, concurrent iterations, each call to `__iter__` method needs to return a distinct iterator instance. So we define a new class, `FooIterator`, that can be used to iterate a `Foo` instance:

```py
class FooIterator:
    def __init__(self, foo_instance):
        self._container = foo_instance._container
        self._current_index = 0

    def __next__(self):
        # Any more items to iterate?
        if self._current_index < len(self._container):
            item = self._container[self._current_index]
            self._current_index += 1
            return item
        # No more items to iterate:
        raise StopException
```

Now each `for/in` loop uses its own iterator instance modifying its own `self._current_index` attribute. And our `Foo` class is modified as follows:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._container = [] # for holding the items

    def add_item(self, item):
        self._container.append(item)

    def __iter__(self):
        return FooIterator(self)
```

Comment: Can you provide more explanation on the `__iter__` function and the class within it `class SinglyLinkedListIterator`?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a brief introduction to iterators. But a search on 'Python iterators' will return many hits for you to read.

Answer (score 0):

**In modern Python, default to dataclasses**. Unless you have a specific reason
to do otherwise, every class you define should be a dataclass, because it's
easier (less boilerplate code) and better (more feature-rich from the outset).

**Mimic great ideas: take an iterable**. Python's built-in lists and tuples are great.
Your linked list implementation should copy the good ideas from those
collection types. For example, when initializing a list, I can pass a sequence
of values: `xs = list('abcd')`. The interface for a linked list should be
similar: take an optional iterable and use it to populate the collection.

**Mimic great ideas: support direct iteration**. Did I mention that Python is
great? One reason is that you can directly iterate over collections: `for x in xs: print(x)`. If your linked list implemention supported direct iteration, the
HackerRank coding task becomes trivial -- worse, it becomes somewhat misguided.
Even if I found myself needing to print the values in a linked list many times, I probably
would not start by writing a function to do it. Instead, I would be more likely
to write a property to return the node values as a sequence.

**Should `Node` be an implementation detail**? Probably not. Why would anyone
bother with a linked list in the first place? Typically because of the need to
add or remove elements without having to process the whole list. That's the
superpower of a linked list. The user of your `SinglyLinkedList` class won't be
able to do those things that if you hide the `Node` instances from them.

```python
import sys
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

def main(args):
    # Printing is no more difficult that joining.
    sll = SinglyLinkedList(args)
    print('\n'.join(sll.values))

class SinglyLinkedList:

    def __init__(self, it = ()):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        # Take an iterable to populate the linked list.
        for value in it:
            self.insert_node(value)

    def insert_node(self, value):
        node = Node(value)
        if self.head:
            self.tail.next = node
        else:
            self.head = node
        self.tail = node

    def __iter__(self):
        # Return an object that can keep track of the
        # current Node during iteration.
        return LinkedListIter(self.head)

    @property
    def values(self):
        return tuple(n.value for n in self)

# Dataclasses!
@dataclass
class Node:
    value: object
    next: 'Node' = field(default = None, repr = False)

@dataclass
class LinkedListIter:
    current: Node

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        c = self.current
        if c:
            self.current = c.next
            return c
        else:
            raise StopIteration

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```